# Make changes without stopping and starting pm2

Tags: node.js, nginx

If I make a node.js code change and upload the file via ftp, the changes don't seem to take effect until I run `pm2 stop app` and then `pm2 start app`. I am pretty sure that isn't the way it should work as this means a period of downtime every time you need to make a change. I found this in the documentation:

> Hot Reload allows to update an application without any downtime:

```
pm2 reload all
```

But wanted to confirm that this is what I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/). You can do `pm2 start app.js --watch`.
with --watch flag it will start watching for changes in any file in directory

> PM2 can automatically restart your application when a file is modified in the current directory or its subdirectories:
>   pm2 start app.js --watch

Comment: That sounds quite good apart from this: "Watching system does not provide any graceful action, pm2 kills and restarts your application without sending SIGINT"